# RDS MySQL 50% CPU usage spike

Tags: mysql, rds

We have a big RDS multi-az instance in prod (probably too big for its purpose atm), but it showed 2 spikes for ~50%.

[rds mysql 50% spikes screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJhIm.jpg)

Never seen that instance rise above 5% since we created it more than 6 months ago. Unfortunately, I didn't setup slow query log (am doing that now), and error log is empty. AWS status page is showing all green for RDS.

I realize it's kind of pointless to be asking for feedback without slow query log, but has anyone else at least experienced this? Anything else I can check? How worried should I be?

P.S: At this point, I'm not convinced it's application code since we've had no interruptions/changes lately and no usage spikes either.

Comment: Nothing really to worry about, and not uncommon with RDS. Don't pay too much attention to small CPU spikes on cloud hosting platforms unless they cause a performance problem. As your hardware access is limited, so are your possible follow-up options.

Comment: try to contact aws support so they can check the underlying instance for any issue, and enable enhanced monitoring and logs for future cases.